# Create git repo in home directory

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, repo

The Repo can't init in Ubuntu 20.04

I just installed repo tool but can't init with bellow error:

```
(base) toan@toan:~$ repo init
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/toan/.repo/manifests.git'
manifests: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/toan/.repo/manifests.git'
fatal: cannot obtain manifest git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git

(base) toan@toan:~$ git version
git version 2.25.1
```

Could you help me solve this problem?

Thanks & BRs
Toan

Comment: Wait a minute, are you trying to create a repository in your own home directory? That makes no sense!

Comment: Thanks for your question! could you help to guide me how to create a repository in your own home directory?

Comment: When I used the "git init" command the content will saw as bellow:

(base) toan@toan:~$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/toan/.git/

Comment: You should *not* create a git repository of your own home directory. Create a *new* directory, `cd` into it, and create the repository there.

Comment: Hello!
I already solved this problem by used "rm -rfv .repo" and "rm -rfv /usr/local/sbin/repo"
We should delete all repo in another directory if we don't use it
Thanks